# Angular material table with expanded rows to be sticky, once it has been scrolled past to remove that sticky row

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material table v11.1.0 having a main row with expand rows on it, that main row would be sticky once you expanded the row and as well as when you scroll the table.

I would like to achieve it like, when we scroll the table, once the expand rows scrolled past the table then we need to remove that sticky from main row. I am trying to find the scroll position to find the expand row to identify it, but no luck. if any help would be appreciated.

My example is here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-expandable-rows-with-sort-search-st-qj5ctn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to detect the scroll event for it, so you can achieve it by adding scroll event to **div**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z0" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

and then you have to get the element for which you want to check its position according to view port.

```
(click)="expandeElment(element, $event.target)"
```

in the ts files you first have define the method OnScroll for the one mentioned in the template.

```
onScroll(event){
 console.log(this.getElementViewportInfo(this.expandedElem))
}
```

then we have to get the html element/row for which we will be targeting in scroll

```
expandeElment(data, element){
  this.expandedElement = data;
  this.expandedElem = element;
  console.log(this.getElementViewportInfo(this.expandedElem))
}
```

in the end we have to add method to get the element view port info

```
getElementViewportInfo(el) {
  const box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return box.top < window.innerHeight && box.bottom >= 0;
}
```

for now I am just console logging the info, if the element is on screen or not, you can further modify according to your changes.

**Note:** solution can be accessed [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-expandable-rows-with-sort-search-st-76jtsm?file=app/table-sorting-example.ts)